# The following exception occurred while retrieving the type name hierarchy: "Not found"

Tags: powershell, wmi

I'm having an awful time trying to save network shares settings. I seem to have deleted something when experimenting with properties.

Here's the code and the error:

```
new-object system.management.managementclass win32_trustee

new-object : The following exception occurred while retrieving the type name hierarchy: "Not found ".
At line:1 char:1
+ new-object system.management.managementclass win32_trustee
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-Object], ExtendedTypeSystemException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CatchFromBaseGetTypeNameHierarchy,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand
```

How does Powershell use WMI and where can I go and check if the class has been deleted?

Edit: 
Thanks to all. I will reply here since I have better formatting tools.

@Mathias R. Jessen

```
gwmi win32_trustee
gwmi : Invalid class "win32_trustee"


[wmi]"win32_trustee"
Cannot convert value "win32_trustee" to type "System.Management.ManagementObject". Error: "Specified argument was out of the range of valid values."

Get-CimInstance win32_trustee
Get-CimInstance : Invalid class
```

@JosefZ

```
Get-TypeData wmiclass
TypeName                     Members                                                           
--------                          -------                                                           
System.Management.ManagementClass {[Name, System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.AliasPropertyData]}


[wmiclass].Assembly.Location
C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Management\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Management.dll


Get-Command *-type*
CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source                                              
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------                                              
Cmdlet          Add-Type                                           3.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility                        
Cmdlet          Get-TypeData                                       3.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility                        
Cmdlet          Remove-TypeData                                    3.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility                        
Cmdlet          Update-TypeData                                    3.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility 


new-object wmiclass win32_trustee
new-object : The following exception occurred while retrieving the type name hierarchy: "Not found ".
```

EDIT: 
The question has been answered at this link:
https://serverfault.com/questions/820267/problems-creating-win32-trustee-object/820482#820482

Here is the answer:
**You can try recompiling the MOF file. Win32_Trustee is part of the secrcw32.mof located in %SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\
Open an elevated command prompt and run the following:
mofcomp.exe %SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\secrcw32.mof
More information on recompiling WMI MOFs is available at: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askperf/2009/04/13/wmi-recompiling-wmi-mofs/**

Comment: Have you tried alternatives, to diagnose the source of the problem (wmi/auth/powershell)? gwmi win32_trustee? [wmi]"win32_trustee"? Get-CmiInstance win32_trustee?

Comment: Simply export/import the registry key [`HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Shares`](http://www.planetcobalt.net/sdb/share_migration.shtml) if you want to save/restore network shares. Otherwise please elaborate on what you want to achieve and show a more complete sample of your code.

Comment: Lost type reference or registration?  Check `Get-TypeData wmiclass` and `[wmiclass].Assembly.Location`. Related: `Get-Command *-type*`. Try  `new-object wmiclass win32_trustee`.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen `gwmi win32_trustee 
gwmi : Invalid class "win32_trustee"


[wmi]"win32_trustee"
Cannot convert value "win32_trustee" to type "System.Management.ManagementObject". Error: "Specified argument was out of the 
range of valid values.

Get-CimInstance win32_trustee
Get-CimInstance : Invalid class `

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers  What I'm trying to do is to export/import network shares with their permissions from one OS to another. I will create a new thread for this. I was mainly having issues with the SID which is inside the Trustee class, but as I said, I seem to have lost that class. I have updated my first post with errors.

Comment: Share migration is an ifrastructure administration task, so [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/) might be a better place for this question.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers  You mean the question of the error message or the migration?

Comment: @Mack I would argue that both are better suited for SF. However, regardless of where you post the question you need to show more of your code.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers OK no problem. I will try posting at Server Fault. The question posted here was only aimed at fixing the error message and nothing else. When you create a new object win32_trustee you get, well, an object with methods and properties and a namespace in Root\cimv2. I get an error message and that's the code that I have in the first post. I followed the suggestion of the others and posted the results also. Other than that I'm not sure what other code I need to post. Thanks for having tried to help.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers By the way which tags should I use at Server Fault? I don't have any experience with this.

Comment: I guess I'll  go with Windows, Powershell, NetworkShare or something like that.

Comment: @Mack I'd probably start with [tag:windows] [tag:network-share] [tag:migration] [tag:powershell]. BTW, you did read my blog post on the subject, didn't you?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Where is your blog?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I didn't know it was a link. Anyways, I've read your blog. I got it to work yesterday doing it the hard way: WMI Classes. I was having difficulty importing the SID back in binary mode but I got it to work. I export the SIDString to .csv, then convert to binary using GetBinaryForm() when importing. But most of the difficulty came from the repeated objects that were being ouput because the filters were not used properly. There should only be one object per share but starting at the DACL layer there should be as many ACE's as there are Trustees.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Other than that, it's also confusing how the DACL/ACE layers appeared to have been merged together. I'm comparing it to the Image that shows hierarchy of these WMI Classes at this link:<https://winception.files.wordpress.com/2011/02/capture-share-security-hierarchy.png> Anyways, that solved my problem. I don't wanna make this post too long and get in trouble. Thanks for the help!